# How to count resource doesn't have like on sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my SQL query. I want to count how many like (count) resources just have  one issue in my count I want the result to be like down but I have problem if resource has 0 like it will not show it result cone someone help me

```
select 
    l.resourceID, COUNT(*) as Count_of_like 
from 
    Likes l 
group by 
    l.resourceID
```

The result I want

```
resourceID  Count_of_like
----------- -------------
1           1
2           2
3           0
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume there is a `Resource` table with an `Id` column?

Comment: What is the like table structure? Is there an ID primary key ?

Comment: yes their are id as PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `resources` table with all of the `resourceId` values. You can JOIN the tables using a LEFT JOIN which will return all rows from the `resources` table even if there is not a matching row in the `likes` table.:

```
select r.resourceid, count(l.resourceId) Total
from resources r
left join likes l
  on r.resourceid = l.resourceid
group by r.resourceid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/914f7/2).

Answer (score 2):

It's a little difficult to understand your question, but I'll assume you have a Resource table as well?  Assuming so, you need to use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
select r.resourceId, count(l.*) Count_of_like 
from resource r 
   left join likes l on r.resourceId = l.resourceId
group by r.resourceId
```

- [Visual Representation of SQL JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)